# Ubuntu 12.10 x64 booting problem

Tags: boot

Just last night I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo G580.

Specs:
Core i5 3rd Gen
4 GB RAM
500 GB HDD
Intel HD 4000 IGP

I'm dual booting between Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.10. But now I'm facing a problem while booting Ubuntu. It sometimes boots, but sometimes it doesn't. I get a black screen with a window saying:

> Your display, graphics card, input devices are not detected properly, You need to reconfigure it.

But sometimes I don't face such problem, it just boots alright. When it boots, I can see that it shows "Graphics : Intel Ivybridge" in "About this computer".

So what's wrong? Any solution?

really? nobody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should set a default VGA card used during boot. That can be done in BIOS.

Comment: i only have one IGP

Comment: It seems like a bug to me. Is your BIOS upgraded?

Comment: no its all what came with laptop
windows7 boots all fine everytime